# How to dynamically update a sitemap with php?

Tags: php, xml, sitemap

I have a dynamic site where posts are constantly being generated i have it coded so each time a new post is added it appends the site map url entry to the bottom of the sitemap.xml file.

```
        $lastID = $db->lastInsertId();
    $file = 'sitemap.xml';
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    $current .= "<url>
    <loc>http://website.net/viewpost.php?ID=".$lastID."</loc>
    <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>";
    file_put_contents($file, $current);
```

this works but the closing tag in the xml file urlset needs to be at the end of the file. So when i append this data it goes after the urlset and even if i added this to the string there would be multiple closing tags for this. How do i update the file so it doesnt go after the closing tag.
Regenerating the entire site map every time would work but it seems like a lot of work as there are almost 100 pages as of right now and it will need to query multiple tables to get the data

Comment: Use an [XML parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) and add the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple function for inserting an element before,after or inside another element.

```
<?php 

public function myInsertNode($newNode, $refNode, $insertMode=null) {

    if(!$insertMode || $insertMode == "inside") {

        $refNode->appendChild($newNode);

    } else if($insertMode == "before") {

        $refNode->parentNode->insertBefore($newNode, $refNode);

    } else if($insertMode == "after") {

        if($refNode->nextSibling) {
            $refNode->parentNode->insertBefore($newNode, $refNode->nextSibling);
        } else {
            $refNode->parentNode->appendChild($newNode);
        }      

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: ok cool so i need to use the before part to insert before </urlset> but surely that requires 3 variables. the filename the string/tagi want to insert before and the data i want to insert?